# How to get source code of this website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get source code (html, css and script) of a specific section on this website:
http://damnripped.com/tdee-calculator/

this is for my project. It's easy to get the html, even css however im unable to pick the scripts using chrome's "inspect element" or "view source code feature".

could somebody please help? I want to get the code for "TDEE calculator" form on the above said page.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever think about learning to do it by yourself instead of copy pasting ?

Comment: I have made tens of such programs since last week but failing in 2-3 steps. The webpage shows a program and thats exactly what I need. Sometimes, learning comes from copy pasting unless you claim you made it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Wordpress plugin anyway: https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/calculated-fields-form/

So it is all open source and free to look at.

Comment: This is it! You are the man! Thanks a lot! You have no clue what have you done - it was a big relief! This plugin made me do this job in a day.. i have been trying for days now. thanks again, I really appreciate!

Answer (score -1):

You can use HTTrack to grab all website content including image, css, html, javascript.

You can download HTTrack [**here**](http://www.httrack.com/page/2/)